# Convert string to object in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string in this format:

```
var x = "a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4"
```

and I would like to convert it to an object like this:

```
var y = {
    a: "1",
    b: "2",
    c: "3",
    d: "4"
    }
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: So show us what you have tried so far

Comment: i tried x.split(";") wich give me ["a=1", "b=2", "c=3", "d=4"].
and i'm thinking to do another split by "=" for each item in the table... ?

Comment: And what's wrong with the solution you're talking about?

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/. You want to create a JavaScript object, not JSON. Either way, simply split the string (multiple times) and create a new object from the parts. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: actually, what i'm trying to do is to parse a mail header.
here is the function:

mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
    var dkim = mail.headers["dkim-signature"].split(";")
    // .....
}

since i'm running that in nodejs(asynchronously), it gets messed up as i try to boocle over the table...

Comment: @SoufianeMghanen you could make your life easier by sending as '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}' .. JSON could be parsed directly in to an object with `JSON.parse(val)` .. reformatting the string where you obtain your values would be the most sane way to handle the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in iE9+

```
var x = "a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4",
    y = {};

x.split(';').map(function (i) {
  return i.split('=')
}).forEach(function (j) {
  y[j[0].trim()] = j[1]
});
```

If you are using Node.js v4+

```
let x = "a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4",
    y = {}

x.split(';').map(i => i.split('=')).forEach(j => y[j[0].trim()] = j[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (not bullet proof, refer to comments):

```js
var json, str;
str = 'a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4';
str = str.replace(/\s*;\s*/g, ',');
str = str.replace(/([^,]+)=([^,]+)/g, '"$1":"$2"');
str = '{' + str + '}';
json = JSON.parse(str);

document.write(
  '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json) + '</pre>'
);
```

Comment: i get this error

{"v":"1," "a":"rsa-sha256," "c":"simple/simple," "d":"X.XXXXX.XXX
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: @SoufianeMghanen The input seems to be more complicated than you said x-) Can you post the actual string please?

Comment: You would have to escape any `"` that occurs in the value. You also have to make sure to escape any escape sequences that have a special meaning in JSON and any occurrence of ``\`` otherwise. Also this approach will fail if any of the values itself contains a `,`.

Answer (score -1):

here is what i did and it seems to work fine:

```
var y = x.split(";");
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < y.length ; i++){
    var k = y[i].split("=");
    var r = k[0].replace(" ", "");
    obj[r] = k[1];
}
console.log(obj);
```